# Hexagon shaped image via markup?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create hexagon shaped elements that will display an image provided by a third party app. Since the images are provided dynamically, I need to inject them into the markup. Ideally the format would look something like:

```
<div class="hexagon">
    <!-- get the image and put it in the hexagon -->
    <img src="foo"/>
</div>
```

I have found numerous tutorials on how to display hex shaped images using `background` styles in css, but no prescriptions for what I'm attempting here.

The closest I have come to solving this is using border shapes, but ran into issues of overlapping when trying to fit the hexagons into a honeycomb pattern. I am currently the the '60deg rotation' method, but still no dice :(

[Check out my pen for reference](http://codepen.io/rdnydnns/pen/jBohK?editors=110), thanks!